# Dividing one xts by another and creating a new xts in the process

Tags: r, xts

I'm looking to divide two xts objects by each other.  Each xts has the same number of columns (with the same column names) but different numbers of rows.  I would like my code to find its respective column in the the other xts and locate the respective date value and divide them then put the new output in a new xts with the same column.

For example:

xts 1

```
Date         V1     V2
2017-07-21   4.5    NA
2017-09-15   NA     2.5
```

xts 2

```
Date         V1     V2
2017-06-15  12.9   10.7
2017-07-21   6.7    2.2
2017-08-13   7.9    8.3
2017-09-15   4.5    3.2
```

new xts

```
Date         V1     V2
2017-07-21  0.67    NA
2017-09-15   NA    1.28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `xts` library is actually a pretty amazing tool and it does that automatically

```
> xts1 <- structure(c(4.5, NA, NA, 2.5), .Dim = c(2L, 2L),
   .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2")),
   index = structure(c(1500595200, 1505433600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"),
   class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date",
   .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC")
> xts2 <- structure(c(12.9, 6.7, 7.9, 4.5, 10.7, 2.2, 8.3, 3.2),
   .Dim = c(4L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2")),
   index = structure(c(1497484800, 1500595200, 1502582400, 1505433600),
       tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"),
   class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date",
   .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC")
> xts1 / xts2
                  V1      V2
2017-07-21 0.6716418      NA
2017-09-15        NA 0.78125
```

Arithmetic operations will respect dates and match them before doing anything.

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for editing @JoshuaUlrich, will try to post more complete answers in the future

Comment: Not your fault.  The original question wasn't reproducible, and your answer was spot-on.  The only thing I would have added was an example people could run, so I did.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `apply`:

```
> t(apply(xts1, 1, function(d)as.numeric(xts1[d[1],c('V1', 'V2')])/as.numeric(xts2[d[1],c('V1', 'V2')])))
                [,1]    [,2]
2017-07-21 0.6716418      NA
2017-09-15        NA 0.78125
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Very helpful.  Suppose I have many columns (over 100), could I change the "c('V1','V2')" to "names(xts1)"?

Comment: Or better `names(xts1)[-1]`, because otherwise you would get an error when dividing the 'Date' fields

Comment: Thanks.  I'm getting this a debugging message "Error in if (!all(i <= 0)) stop("only zeros may be mixed with negative subscripts") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed".