# Dividing one xts by another and creating a new xts in the process / additional question

Tags: r, xts

I would refer to this question: [Dividing one xts by another and creating a new xts in the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917271/dividing-one-xts-by-another-and-creating-a-new-xts-in-the-process/49919456#49919456?newreg=adde987a35134cc6a1b71d2d552e9bbf)

I am wondering if it is possible to get exactly the same code but without using time zone data. Because I have only dates like 2017-06-15, 2017-07-21 ect. But the result should be the same (ratios should be the same).  I have tried to change the code by deleting references to time zone, but then I get an error: In tzone.xts(x) :
object does not have a ‘tzone’ or ‘.indexTZ’ attribute.

Comment: Please, share your codes and add some tags.